How to filter XML attribute in Ansible?
Output below is log message and I need to retrieve log count which is 5.
Code
- name: get system log count
  connection: local
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ log.content }}"
    content: attribute
    xpath: '/response/result/log/logs[@count]'
  register: log_count

- name: print log count
  debug:
    msg: "{{ log_count.matches }}"

Output
ok: [10.46.255.101] => {
    "msg": {
        "actions": {
            "namespaces": {},
            "state": "present",
            "xpath": "/response/result/log/logs[@count]"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "count": 1,
        "failed": false,
        "matches": [
            {
                "logs": {
                    "count": "5",
                    "progress": "100"
                }
            }
        ]

How to filter log count and use that as condition in next task?
How to modify this code to store value of count (5) in a variable use it as condition in next task? I tries to use log_count.matches.count that doesn't work.
Basically I am trying to get count value from this output
<response status="success"><result>
  <job>
    <tenq>05:03:36</tenq>
    <tdeq>05:03:36</tdeq>
    <tlast>05:03:36</tlast>
    <status>FIN</status>
    <id>90</id>
  </job>
  <log>
    <logs count="0" progress="100"/>
  </log>
</result></response>


Q: "I am trying to get count value from this output"
Based on How to fetch value from an API response with Ansible playbook?, a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'response.xml') }}"
    YML: "{{ XML | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ YML }}"

  - name: Logs count
    debug:
      msg: "{{ YML.response.result.log.logs['@count'] }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    response:
      '@status': success
      result:
        job:
          id: '90'
          status: FIN
          tdeq: 05:03:36
          tenq: 05:03:36
          tlast: 05:03:36
        log:
          logs:
            '@count': '0'
            '@progress': '100'

TASK [Logs count] ************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '0'

Q: "How to use that as condition in the next task?"
In example
  - fail:
      msg: No logs!
    when: YML.response.result.log.logs['@count'] | int < 1

resulting into an output of
TASK [fail] ********************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: No logs!


Based on your initial problem description and example, the content of the registed variable log_count is
TASK [debug] *********************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  log_count:
    actions:
      namespaces: {}
      state: present
      xpath: /response/result/log/logs[@count]
    changed: false
    count: 1
    failed: false
    matches:
    - logs:
        count: '0'
        progress: '100'
    msg: 1
    xmlstring: |-
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
      <response status="success"><result>
        <job>
          <tenq>05:03:36</tenq>
          <tdeq>05:03:36</tdeq>
          <tlast>05:03:36</tlast>
          <status>FIN</status>
          <id>90</id>
        </job>
        <log>
          <logs count="0" progress="100"/>
        </log>
      </result></response>

Return Values under matches are a list, in your case with one element only. You can get the count in a similar way as already shown.
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'response.xml') }}"

  tasks:

  - community.general.xml:
      xmlstring: "{{ XML }}"
      content: attribute
      xpath: '/response/result/log/logs[@count]'
    register: log_count

  - debug:
      var: log_count

  - name: Logs count
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (log_count.matches | first).logs.count }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [Logs count] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '0'


A note regarding dependencies ... Whereby xml module requires

on the host that executes this module. lxml >= 2.3.0

the from_xml filter  does not.
